# Bind HashMap inside Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am trying to use android data-binding library. In order to get started with it I am trying to use HashMap but getting some errors. Here is my code:

MyActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;
    HashMap<String, String> myMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("one", "ONE");
        myMap.put("two", "TWO");
        myMap.put("three", "THREE");
        activityMainBinding.setMap(myMap);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <variable
                name="map"
                type="java.util.HashMap" />

             <variable
                  name="one"
                  type="String" />

        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{map[one]}" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Error:

> Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text' with parameter type V on android.widget.TextView.

Comment: try: android:text="@{map.get(one)}"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618116/android-databinding-possible-to-bind-values-from-a-hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concern is that `HashMap` is a generic class. You can't assign any generic type to you data binding in xml. So, what you need to do is add some wrapper for your `HashMap` without generic. Like that:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapContainer {

    public String get(String key) {
        return getMap().get(key);
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
        HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("one", "ONE");
        myMap.put("two", "TWO");
        myMap.put("three", "THREE");
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

After that you can define a function get inside your data binding class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="map"
            type="changeThisVariableToYourProjectPackage.MapContainer" />

        <variable
            name="one"
            type="String" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{map.get(one)}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @samaromku's answer just change :

```
android:text="@{map.get(`one`)}
```

or

```
android:text='@{map.get("one")}'
```